# Google Cloud DNS & ProtonMail DKIM records

Tags: dns, google-cloud-platform, dkim, google-cloud-dns

ProtonMail has rolled out support for receiving mail from [custom domains](https://protonmail.com/support/knowledge-base/anti-spoofing/), and I'm adding the necessary records to my project's Cloud DNS settings from within Google Cloud Platform. I added the MX and SPF records, and they checked out, but when I try to add the DKIM records I get a "Not Properly Set" error from ProtonMail's end. I followed the same format, putting `protonmail._domainkey` in the hostname, adding it as a `TXT` record, and including `v=DKIM1; k=rsa; p=...` in the record value.

ProtonMail technical support wasn't very helpful, replying with a "we don't see your TXT DKIM records, please ensure they are being properly propagated" response.

I can provide the other records I've set if anyone thinks it would be helpful.

Comment: It would probably be helpful to know the domain name, to check and see how they look - if you put it in a comment you can always delete it later

Answer (score 0):

Your DKIM record may need to be wrapped in quotes.

Try:

```
"v=DKIM1; k=rsa; p=..."
```

I had the exact same issue with DKIM on protonmail. Protonmail support suggested verifying the records via mxtoolbox.com. Since I could see that my TXT record wasn't showing up as I had written it, I emailed my domain provider for help. They added quotes to the TXT record, and then I could see the record properly on mxtoolbox.com.

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to retrieve your DKIM record with this tool:
http://mxtoolbox.com/dkim.aspx

Enclosing your DKIM TXT entry in quotes may solve the issue. Many DKIM libraries have issues with spaces after the semicolons.

Did you attempt to use a key larger than 1024 bits?

If you provide the domain name that your are having an issue with, I will look at the DKIM information in the zone.